# Double integral with domain $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multiple-integral

> Find the double integral 
>   $$\iint_D\frac{1}{(1+2x^2+y^2)^2}\; dx \; dy$$
>   where $D=\{(x,y)|x \geq  0,y\geq 0\}$,  using $ x=ar\cos \theta$, $y=br \sin \theta$.

So i got the jacobian $abr$
but i wasnt so sure about the domain, and the domain widen, and my book said that $2x^2+y^2\leq c^2$, $x\geq 0,y\geq 0$. First why I have to use $c$? and how can I define the domain in problem like this? Is the domain said that it is in first quadrant?

$2x^2+y^2\leq c^2$ how can i get this inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $D$ is the first quadrant and the jacobian is correct.

Let $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=1$. Then $x=\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$,  $2x^2+y^2=r^2$, and
$$D=\{(x,y):x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}=\left\{\left(\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{2}},r\sin(\theta)\right): r\geq 0 ,\;0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2\right\}.$$
Hence
$$\iint_D\frac{1}{(1+2x^2+y^2)^2}\; dx \; dy=\int_{r=0}^{+\infty} \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+r^2)^2}\cdot\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}d\theta\,dr.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks!! how can i know that $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $b=1$?? where it come from? and why $ 2x^2+y^2 <= c$?

Comment: we choose $a$ and $b$ in such a way that $2x^2+y^2=r^2$. Here $c$ is the same of $r$. $2x^2+y^2\leq r^2$ is the region inside an ellipse, by letting $r\to +\infty$ we get the whole plane.

Comment: $2x^2+y^2=r^2$ why it has to be equal to $r^2$? and i have to draw this $\frac{1}{(1+2x^2+y^2)^2}$  first?

Comment: so here you got $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $b=1$ from $\frac{x^2}{1/2}+\frac{y^2}{1}=1$ ? so it is ellips with $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $b=1$, center 0,0 ?

Comment: oh i think i just realized, $2x^2+y^2\leq r^2$ because we want to convert it to polar coordinate, so in order to make it easy to substitute and thats why we use jacobian too!

Comment: @fiksx Well done! So what is the final result?

Comment: i tried it and i got $\frac{\pi }{4 \sqrt 2}(1- \frac{1}{1+r^2})$, but do i need to take the limit to infinity and why? and also i have one more problem, i want to know $\iint_D\frac{1}{(1+2x^2+y^2)^2}\; dx \; dy$ , can i calculate this integral using above method? or i cannot use jacobian here? thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to take the limit as $r\to \infty$. You are integrating on the whole first quadrant which is unbounded!

Comment: ok! but i mean in problem like this, i know the domain is in first quadrant, but  $2x^2+y^2\leq r^2$ the use of this equation is to determined the bound for $r$ in polar coordinate? so its inside elips?

Comment: In fact the upper limit of $r$ is $+\infty$ because  $2x^2+y^2\leq r^2$ and $x$ and $y$ are unbounded in the first quadrant.

Comment: oh! so the upper limit is infinity, that is why we use improper integral because of x and y unbounded? so its like having an ellips but the bounded will be infinity? with $a=1/ \sqrt 2$ and $b=1$ and the use of the polar coordinate just to make easier to count?

Comment: Yes, as $r\to \infty$, the ellipse $2x^2+y^2\leq r^2$ grows and cover the whole plane. By taking  $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$ we select the first quadrant.

Comment: ok thankyou so much for answering my questions!!! really appreciate for the help!!!!^^